# Creating tables in SQL

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know how to do this in SQL?

Step 1:
Make a table in MySQL called users with 3 fields atleast.

Step 2:
id is the first make it the primary and also auto_increment.
username is the second.
password is the third one.

If anyone does please give me the code or explain what I need to do, I would like to learn how to do it

-Thank in advance

Comment: do you have cPanel installed on your server?

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysql+create+table

Comment: I do, I have php my admin as well

Comment: Thank you for the link but I want to learn how you would make the tables by the interface first then i'd understand the code if you get me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, if you would like to learn how to do it, you would be best off reading some tutorials on the subject.  A quick [Google for MySQL create table](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysql+create+table) has plenty of suggestions.

I suspect just looking at the code will be *far* less instructive than working through a tutorial or reading the manual, but since you asked:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(50),
    password VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a table in MySQL with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). It's an online tool that helps with rapid prototyping...

Take a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7da8/1